# Number of double cosets of a Young subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $\lambda\vdash n$ be a partition of $n$ with $k$ parts and $S_\lambda$ be a Young subgroup of $S_n$. 
Further let $S_\lambda\backslash S_n/ S_\lambda$ be the set of double-cosets. Now I would like to get the most general bound on the number of these cosets. All I could come up with is roughly $n^{k^2}$ but I wonder if this is not far to big.. For example in the cases $\lambda=(n-k,k)$ I think that there are only  $k$ such double cosets.

Comment: You need to add a broader tag such as 'group-theory'.  Aside from that, Richard's answer reflects the fact that a great deal is known about symmetric groups; so your question is certainly not new.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a standard result that the number of double cosets of the pair
$(S_\lambda, S_\mu)$ is the number of matrices of nonnegative integers
with row sum vector $\lambda$ and column sum vector $\mu$. See for
instance Exercise 7.77 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2. This
makes it clear, for instance, why there are only $k+1$ double cosets
when $\lambda=\mu=(n-k,k)$. There are also many
known estimates for the number of matrices of nonnegative integers
with given row and column sum vectors. An example is the paper
http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/asymptotics.pdf by Barvinok
and Hartigan.